# TP-Link TL-WN823N V2 does not work with rtl8192eu driver on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, drivers, realtek-wireless

I followed these [steps](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2351228&p=13601820#post13601820) to setup rtl192eu driver for my TP-Link TL-WN823N wifi device and `dkms status` showed me that it was installed, but the connection is unstable, and I need to reconnect constantly to the wireless network.

[Device TP-Link TL-WN823N V2](https://www.tp-link.com/en/download/TL-WN823N_V2.html#Driver)
Ubuntu 16.04

How do I solve this? Why does ubuntu do not support this device automatically?

Comment: What is the exact response to the terminal commands: `sudo dkms status` and also: `sudo modprobe 8192eu` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: dkms status return "rtl8192eu, 1.0, 4.13.0-41-generic, x86_64: installed" and "8192eu" does not return anything

Comment: I am using my home computer and it is working normally, but using the same device at my work computer sometimes gets unstable and stops working unexpectedly, as if the device did not exist. Maybe kernel version is not the same? 
How can I know which kernel is supported by this driver?

Comment: From the office, when it is not running correctly, please run and post: `dmesg | grep -e wlx -e 8192`

Comment: I will post the dmesg result when I'm at work on monday, thank you

Comment: I edited the question with dmesg and wireless-info information after the device is not working

Comment: Is this a cold boot with no other modprobes to load a driver? We are puzzled as to why the unrelated rt2800usb loaded. What does this tell us? `modinfo 8192eu | grep 0109`

Comment: Sorry, but I can't understand the first question. The rt2800usb is another wireless device that I am using while my TP-Link(8192eu) does not work. When you ask me to type the commands in the terminal, I unplug rt2800usb and plug the 8192eu. 
Maybe this device switch that is confusing the results? 
Unfortunately I need to do this, because I do not have cable internet.  I need to use the rt2800usb device to be able to connect to the internet

Comment: modinfo 8192eu | grep 0109 -> modinfo: ERROR: Module 8192eu not found.

Comment: sudo modprobe 8192eu -> modprobe: FATAL: Module 8192eu not found in directory /lib/modules/4.13.0-41-generic. 
I think I uninstalled the driver unintentionally. Should I reinstall it again using https://github.com/Mange/rtl8192eu-linux-driver?

Comment: If you want the TP-Link to work, then, yes, I suggest that you reinstall its driver.

Comment: After installing the driver I mentioned, it started working again. I connected to a wireless network and I used it for 5 minutes and the connection to that wireless network dropped, I had to reconnect again to continue the use. This is happening constantly, the connection is unstable. What can it be?

Comment: Check the log: `dmesg | grep -e wlx -e 8192`

Comment: Result: https://pastebin.com/ZnWtCV0B

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77813/discussion-between-gustavo-piucco-and-chili555).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After intalling 8192eu driver as following:

```
sudo apt-get install git build-essential dkms
git clone https://github.com/Mange/rtl8192eu-linux-driver.git
sudo dkms add ./rtl8192eu-linux-driver
sudo dkms install -m rtl8192eu -v 1.0
```

I noticed instabilities and weak signal. I solved it as follows:

```
echo "options 8192eu rtw_power_mgnt=0 rtw_enusbss=0" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/8192eu.conf
echo "blacklist rtl8xxxu" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8xxxu.conf
```

Reboot.

Comment: After looking everywhere this actually fixed my slow wifi issue. A very under rated answer.