# Tl-wn823n ubuntu 22.04

Tags: wireless, signal

Its connect but very week signal router is on desktop still week other device is work properly

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** Your question as currently written is very unclear. Please edit your question to describe your issue "Having Problems with WIFI Connectivity when Running TP-LINK Mini Wireless N USB Adapter." What computer/laptop do you have this USB device attached to (make/model)? What do you mean "weak signal?" Can you provide specific connectivity values (a quick check would be `cat /proc/net/wireless`).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TP-Link TL-WN823N V2 does not work with rtl8192eu driver on Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1037824/tp-link-tl-wn823n-v2-does-not-work-with-rtl8192eu-driver-on-ubuntu-16-04)